# How can I fix this Mixpanel iOS 30-second background task timeout bug (mixpanel-react-native)?

Tags: ios, react-native, background-task, mixpanel

## Problem

My app is occasionally terminating in background after 30 seconds in release mode. The below warning appears after ~30 seconds of the app being sent into the background when running with the Xcode debugger.

> 2022-04-17 13:53:10.414266-0400 Siro[83233:4914219] [BackgroundTask]
> Background Task 297 ("Called by Siro, from
> $s8Mixpanel0A8InstanceC29applicationDidEnterBackground33_0CB45E1C8B4A4433813A640264188496LLyy10Foundation12NotificationVF"),
> was created over 30 seconds ago. In applications running in the
> background, this creates a risk of termination. Remember to call
> UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(_:) for your task in a timely manner
> to avoid this.

Has anyone else encountered this issue or know of a fix?

Per the error message, the issue seems to be caused by the Mixpanel package, but I find it strange that there is not already an issue report about this issue.

A second strange element is that only ~10% of our users have encountered this issue.

Any ideas?

## Environment Information

I do not know if this issue is also occurring on Android

Mixpanel Version: `"mixpanel-react-native": "^1.3.10"`

Output from `npx react-native info`:

> System:
> OS: macOS 12.3.1
> CPU: (10) x64 Apple M1 Pro
> Memory: 745.50 MB / 32.00 GB
> Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh   Binaries:
> Node: 15.13.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v15.13.0/bin/node
> Yarn: Not Found
> npm: 7.7.6 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v15.13.0/bin/npm
> Watchman: 2022.03.21.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman   Managers:
> CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod   SDKs:
> iOS SDK:
> Platforms: DriverKit 21.4, iOS 15.4, macOS 12.3, tvOS 15.4, watchOS 8.5
> Android SDK: Not Found   IDEs:
> Android Studio: 2020.3 AI-203.7717.56.2031.7935034
> Xcode: 13.3.1/13E500a - /usr/bin/xcodebuild   Languages:
> Java: 11.0.15 - /usr/bin/javac   npmPackages:
> @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
> react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2
> react-native: 0.67.4 => 0.67.4

Answer (score 0):

I have not solved the root issue, but I created a workaround by preventing Mixpanel from attempting to flush events when app is sent to background.

https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-react-native/pull/135

I'm still not sure what is causing Mixpanel background tasks to sometimes run for 30+ seconds and cause terminations. Perhaps it is due to weak internet connection.